# Python MySQLdb String Replacement

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to figure out why my mysql insert statement doesn't seem to work with string replacement. Simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="***", passwd="***", db="***")
cur = db.cursor()
a = '1'
b = '2'
c = '3'
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO rented_users (username,login,password) VALUES ('1','2','3')    """)
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO rented_users (username,login,password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);""", (a,b,c)

mysql> describe rented_users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| login    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Basically my first insert statement works fine, but when I try to use the second insert statement using string replacement it fails. It doesn't give me a very descriptive error either.

```
File "insert_test", line 10

                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's weird is this exact same syntax seems to work in a different script fine. Really confused. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO rented_users (username,login,password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);""", (a,b,c)
```

Is missing a closing `)`.

The invalid syntax is probably reported at the next line. This happens because Python syntax lets you add the parentheses on a following line so long as there's only empty space.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I knew it was something simple, wonder why it was working in my other script. Bizarre. Nevertheless thankyou.